# How to create an list of http target cloud tasks with a certain time difference

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I have a firebase cloud function to trigger on write certain file on firebase firestore called `onWriteFile`.

The function `onWriteFile` creates a http cloud task to run on certain time in future like follow:

```
const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks')

exports.onWriteFile = async (event, context) => { 
    const project = 'my-projet'
    const location = 'us-central1'
    const queue = 'on-write-file'

    const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient()
    const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue)

    const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/some-function`

    //here is the core of question
    const timestamp = event.value.fields.timestamp.integerValue
    const json = { id: context.params.id }

    const task = {
        httpRequest: {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            url,
            body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(json)).toString('base64'),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        },
        scheduleTime: {
            seconds: timestamp
        }
    }

    await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task })
};
```

It's work fine for me.

But, how to create amount of tasks with 10 seconds of difference for example in same `onWrieteFile` function?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve: "create amount of tasks with n seconds of difference".

Comment: @DougStevenson the question was edited. 10 seconds is my goal!

Comment: It doesn't really help me to know what n is.  I still don't understand what your goal is.  Maybe you could describe in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did describe this question with bit detail. But I'm solve the problem with follow code:

```
const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks')

exports.onWriteFile = async (event, context) => { 
    const project = 'my-projet'
    const location = 'us-central1'
    const queue = 'on-write-file'

    const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient()
    const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue)

    const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/some-function`

    const timestamp = event.value.fields.timestamp.integerValue
    const json = { id: context.params.id }

    //given a array to iterable
    const iterable = Array.from(Array(6).keys())

    //for each iteration I go add ten seconds to timestamp
    const TEN_SECONDS = 10

    const promises = iterable.map(async (i) => {
        const seconds = Number(timestamp) + Number(i * TEN_SECONDS)
        const task = {
            httpRequest: {
                httpMethod: 'POST',
                url,
                body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(fixtureId)).toString('base64'),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            },
            scheduleTime: {
                seconds: seconds
            }
        }

        return await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task })
    })

    //then, I will have 6 cloud tasks with 10 seconds of difference
    await Promise.all(promises)
};
```

And thanks [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) for [post on Medium](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)